# Drupal 7 Views: Align text with image

Tags: views, display-suite

Hello Drupal Stack Exchange crowd.  I am working on building a *view* for a content type that has several fields and an image. I am using an **"Unformulated list"**

Using Drupal 7 core and the most recent update of views.

**My goal is to align the field image to the right so the text is right next to it.**

I have put the text field and image "Inline" in field settings and "**remove HTML**" formatting and changed the text to "**Plain Text**". This places the text starting at the bottom right corner of the image but I'm wanting the text to align starting at the top right. I have tried rewriting the field to do this but have had no luck.

It seems like something like this would be very simple without `.css` (since I'm not the best at it).

**My Questions are:**

1. If I use `.css`, what style sheet should I insert the code into (Views, Theme, ??)?
2. Is there a way to get around using a `.css` to accomplish what I want to do?

Thank you in advance for your time.
WO

Addition info 10/22/15 - **in response to argiepiano**: I already use and love display suite and have never noticed the "Display Suite" option in Views. THANK YOU. I have gone through the first 5 videos but:  **I still have trouble getting text/images to align correctly in Display Suite (css), do you mayhap know of any good videos or articles on that?**

Thanks Again,
WO

Comment: Question: do you want to display a list of more than one node, or just a single node?

Comment: There will be several nodes displayed, new ones being created daily. I would love some good documentation on creating .css DS field styles after watching those videos from the link here. Thank you again for that!

Questions? Where do I add the .css styles to be used on DS fields (sites/all/modules/ds/css ?) (I'd prefer a location with the quickest load time). Will I need to call the .css from that folder or does it not matter? ..sorry I'm used to HTML.

I think I can figure out the rest from there.

Comment: OK, to create css classes that apply anywhere in your site (including your DS displays) you need to: (1) Create a subtheme of the theme you are using (not absolutely necessary but highly recommended - you don't want to modify your original theme.) See https://www.drupal.org/node/225125. (2) Create a new css file and place it in your subtheme folder. (3) add the line stylesheets[all][]=yourNewCssFile.css. IT may be best to start a new question for longer explanation. These comment boxes have a limited number of characters :)

Comment: There is a lot of documentation on subthemes, I have already gotten my hands dirty and made good progress.I wanted to thank you again for your help here and share a link to a video that may help others in creating a Drupal Subtheme: http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/creating-drupal-7-sub-theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds). This module allows you to define a layout for the entry form and/or the display of any content type. If you want to use Views to create a list of nodes, you can use the layout you created to display each of the nodes in the View by selecting `Unformatted list of Full posts` in the Display format dropdown lists in the Views wizard.

There are several excellent video tutorials for Display Suite, but I'd recommend the [ones its author created](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNEUqu3LdH6YBeoqMcmHe2w).